# Taking a Swing dialog method and converting it to SWT

Tags: java, swing, dialog, swt

I am trying to take the following method of Swing code and migrate to SWT for my application.

I know some of it.

SWT            SWING
Label          JLabel
Button         JButton
Dialog         JDailog
???            Box

The method looks like it is creating a status dialog and has a cancel button.

How could I do the same but in SWT?
I am not sure what Swing Box is doing?
Is this basically a simple dialog with a cancel button and some labels?

```
 private void createPrintDialog() {
    pd = new JDialog((Frame) null, "Printing...", false);
    Container top = pd.getContentPane();
    Box lines = Box.createVerticalBox();
    Box line = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    line.add(new Label("Now printing: "));
    Label title = new Label("file.pdf");
    line.add(title);
    lines.add(line);

    line = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    line.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
    line.add(new Label("page "));
    pagenumlabel = new JLabel("1");
    line.add(pagenumlabel);
    line.add(new JLabel(" of "));
    JLabel totalpages = new JLabel(String.valueOf(file.getNumPages()));
    line.add(totalpages);
    lines.add(line);

    top.add(lines, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    Box cancelbox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    cancelbox.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    cancel = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Cancel") {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            doCancel();
        }
    });
    cancelbox.add(cancel);
    top.add(cancelbox, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of this dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog`. ( There are static method open Error,Info...etc. use it as per your needs)